# set large font size for high resolution device in media-query

Tags: css, responsive-design, media-queries

IPad resolution is 768*1024, but a mobile maybe 720*1024. I want to set larger font for device, so that its size in pt is same as pad. for example:

```
@media (min-width: 700px) {
    #div_test{
    font-size:22px; 
    }
}
```

how to modify the @media condition?

Answer (score 2):

```
@media (min-width: 700px){
  /*code*/
}
```

The `min-width` property in the media query works a little different. It is not the resolution of the screen. It is equivalent css pixel.

Here are a couple of articles.

[A pixel identity crisis](http://alistapart.com/article/a-pixel-identity-crisis).

[A pixel is not a pixel is not a pixel](http://www.quirksmode.org/blog/archives/2010/04/a_pixel_is_not.html).

[moz media query page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries).

If you want to target device resolution you should use

```
@media all and (max-device-width: 320px) {

}.
```

`max-device-width`:This property measures the device-width. If you write css using media query using this it will get a little complex (mobiles tabs and even desktops can have 1080p resolution screens). In order to target device resolutions you might have to look into properties like -`device-pixel-ratio`, `orientation` and `device-height` to give better control of layouts.

[Here is a list of media queries for ipad](http://stephen.io/mediaqueries/)

This media query targets all ipads.

```
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 768px) 
and (max-device-width : 1024px)  { /* STYLES GO HERE */}
```